# Webapi call from jquery failing

Tags: jquery

Below is the code snippet of Jquery to call the webapi method.
    When I call the method `GetAllEmployees()` it returns the data as `undefined` once it leaves the  function the method `Success` is getting called. Why is it happening? I want the result once i call the function

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>GetAllCust</title>
    @*<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>*@

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetAllEmployees()
        {
            var Result;
            // debugger;
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:61883/APIService/api/Employee/GetAllEmployees',// service call
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data)
                {

                    Result = data;// Not returning the data
                    $.each(data, function (index, employee)
                    {
                        console.log(employee.EmpName);
                        alert(employee.EmpName);
                    });
                },
                error: function (x, y, z) {
                    alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
                }
            });
            return Result;//Not sending the result
        }
        // Calling the  method here
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            debugger;
            var EmpData = GetAllEmployees();
            //  I see the empdata as undefined
        });
        //Once i come out from here i see the method  console.log diplsaying the data
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Really confused why does it behaves like this once the function is called it has to return the data why is it called at the end the success function. I actually need the result of the function once it is called based on that further computation is done. Really appreciate any help on this!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi , can you please tell me that you checked the networkTab and you got get request along with data returned from web api?

Comment: Yes i  can see the data coming   in IE using developer tools

Comment: and what is the returned datatype ? you are setting it as json does you response is valid json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is [asynchronous](http://callbackhell.com/). It means that, when you call a function that it is async (like calling your webapi), the JS processing does not wait until it gets the response but goes on. Eventually, when the server responds the callback function is called (in your case `success` method). That is why your `EmpData` is `undefined`. What you can do, is to pass a callback to your `GetAllEmployees`, or use something like [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) if you can use ES6.

**Callbacks**

Consider this:

```
function GetAllEmployees(cb)
        {
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:61883/APIService/api/Employee/GetAllEmployees',// service call
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data)
                {
                    cb(null, data)
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    cb(error, null)
                }
            });
        }
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
  {
     GetAllEmployees(function(err, data){
         if(!err) {
         //here you have access to your data.
         }
     });
  });
```

**Promises**

Similarly, you can use promises to write asynchronous code in synchronous manner. Consider this:

```
function GetAllEmployees() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:61883/APIService/api/Employee/GetAllEmployees',// service call
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data)
            {
                resolve(data)
            },
            error: function (error) {
                reject(error)
            }
        });
    });
}

GetAllEmployees().then(function(data){
    //here you have access to the data
}).catch(function(err){
    //error occurred
})
```

But note, that in order to use promises you need to transpile your code in order to get full browser support.